# Copy dictionary to register in Vim

Tags: dictionary, vim, vim-registers

I have a dictionary in my vimrc that I would like to copy and paste into whatever text file I'm editing:

```
let info = { 'tom':12345, 'bob':54689 }
```

I tried using put as I would with an option setting but I get an error:

```
:put=@info
```

How do I copy the contents of "info" to the register so that I can paste it in my text document?

Comment: `:put=string(info)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting the json data.  And removing `@` from put command (`@` is used to accessed registers, not for variables):

```
:let info="{ 'tom':12345, 'bob':54689 }"
:put=info
```

Comment: This works but doesn't this turn "info" into a string rather than a dictionary? I'd like to keep it as a dictionary if possible so that I can keep the functionality available with a dictionary (e.g. accessing specific keys, etc.).

Comment: I could be wrong but don't registers, by definition, contain text? I don't believe it's possible to store structured data in a register without serializing and deserializing it on the way in and out, respectively.

Comment: @JordanRunning indeed, ":help registers" suggests that registers can only contain strings. It also mentions *"A Dictionary or FuncRef results in an error message (use string() to convert)."*

Answer (score 3):

If you want to maintain the exact representation, you have to store the dictionary as a *string* already (as per @sergio's answer), and you can `:put` it directly.

If it's fine to have Vim render the dictionary (and potentially reorder its elements), you just have to explicitly convert to a string, in order to overcome the `E731: using Dictionary as a String` (as it's [`:help`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#E731) explains, these types are not automatically converted). The [`string()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#string%28%29) function will do that:

```
:put =string(info)
```